# regular exp in python to get values

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file, where I have content with the below format ;

Added for testing

abc (2):
submitted the patch
testing the patch

xyz (1):
working on regular exp

happy ending

I want to write a regular expression to get the values :

> submitted the patch
>
> testing the patch
>
> working on regular exp

My regular expression is not giving me expected value, can anyone help me to sort out this:

```
match = re.search('[\W\w.\s]* \(\d+\):([\n\s\W\w.\d\_\.]*)\n',file)
```

Comment: Sorry, is "abc (2)" part of the file's contents?

Comment: Yes
Starts from Added for testing, ends with happy ending

Comment: Seriously, `[\W\w.\s]`? that matches pretty much anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this if the file format is fixed

```
print "".join(re.findall(r"\(\d+\): *([\s\S]*?)(?=[\r\n]{2,})",x))
```

Output:
  `submitted the patch
  testing the patch
  working on regular exp`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working. Can you please explain me a bit how it is working

Comment: @Sivaprasad it uses `findall` which return a list from the whole string of whatever we r searching.So we say that anything after `an integer followed by :` and before `2` newlines ,we want in a list,then we join it.Do accept if this worked for you

Comment: Yes, it is working. Thanks a million. You saved my time

Comment: is it possible to get all the matched strings in a list, each line as a element in the list

Comment: @Sivaprasad yes remove the `join`.`re.findall(r"\(\d+\): *([\s\S]*?)(?=[\r\n]{2,})",x)`

Comment: ['\n   submitted the patch\n   testing the patch', '\n  working on reg exp']

where as I am expecting

['\n   submitted the patch\n' ,  'testing the patch', '\n  working on reg exp']

Comment: @Sivaprasad u will have to split ur text on `\n`.

Comment: Yes, I used splitlines(). Thanks